# Присвоить переменной JS значение PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть таблица panel.php, которая содержит в себе информацию из БД:

```php
<?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Value` FROM `currency`');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<tr>' .
         "<td>{$result['ID']}</td>" .
         "<td>{$result['Name']}</td>" .
         "<td>{$result['Value']}</td>" .
         "<td><a href='?del_id={$result['ID']}'>Удалить</a></td>" .
         "<td><a href='?red_id={$result['ID']}'>Изменить</a></td>" .
         '</tr>';
  }
?>
```

Данные передаются корректно, с этим проблем никаких нет. Далее я хочу передавать `{$result['Value']}` переменным `convert.js` для изменения коэффициента при расчете:

```js
let usdtMar; // ['Value'] для usdt
let rubMar; // ['Value'] для rub
let uahMar; // ['Value'] для uah
let c = {
    'USDT':s1 * usdtMar,
    'RUB':'1' * rubMar,
    'UAH':s3 / 10 * uahMar,
};
```

Понимаю, что это можно как-то решить с использованием `$.ajax`, но не знаю, как правильно написать запрос для каждой переменной, чтобы она получала необходимое `['Value']`

Comment: В ajax Вы можете вернуть значения за один раз для всех переменных и далее если они находятся в зоне видимости просто присвоить им значения если не находятся в зоне видимости можно прокинуть им значения через функцию, не совсем понятно из фрагментов где что у Вас находится.

Comment: Похожие вопросы уже многократно обсуждались... Вы можете использовать сериализованное JSON представление для передачи всех данных в объект, например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58775567/3129992).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю всех за подсказки, но я решил другим способом. В файл `index.php` добавил следующий php-код:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `Value` FROM `currency` WHERE `ID` = 3");
$usdt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$usdt = $usdt['Value'];
```

Далее в `convert.js` объявил необходимую переменную и присвоил ей значение переменной php, чтобы коэффициент изменялся через админ-панель сайта:

```
let usdtmar = '<?php echo $usdt;?>'
    let c = {
        'USDT':s1 * usdtmar,
        'RUB':'1' * 1.1,
        'UAH':s3 / 10 * 1.05
```

Согласен, что решение не совершенно и требует постоянного объявления переменных для каждой валюты, однако конечный результат меня устроил. В дальнейшем попробую реализовать через парс JSON